# Bijection between different sets of homomorphisms.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a group and let $A$ be and abelian group. Let $G'$ be the commutator of $G$. Prove there is a bijection between the set of homomorphisms $f:G\rightarrow A$ to the set of homomorphisms $ϕ:G/G'\rightarrow A$.

What I do know is that $G/G'$ is abelian and that there is a one-to-one correcpondence between the set of subgroups of $G/G'$ and the set of normal subgroups of $G$ whose quotient is abelian. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: The subgroups of G/G' won't help. But do you remember the universal property of the quotient G/G' ?

Comment: I know some but it won't form into an idea right now...

Comment: You are asked to find a bijection between two sets of homomorphisms. Surely you can get started yourself by suggesting a possible map. For example, given a homomorphism $\phi:G/G' \to A$, how could you define a corresponding homomorphism $f:G \to A$? That shouldn't be too difficult!

Comment: Using a canonical homomorphism g:G/G'→G, g(sG)=s?? Would it be legitimate?

Comment: What confuses me is the fact that I have to find a set bijection but using all along homomorphisms... :((

Comment: The canonical homorphism is $G \to G/G'$ not $G/G' \to G$, and you can use that to define the required map $\tau:{\rm Hom}(G/G',A) \to {\rm Hom}(G,A)$. It should be routine to write down the definition of $\tau$ and to show that $\tau$ is an injective map. The only thing that requires a bit of work is to show that $\tau$ is surjective.

Comment: So it means I won't benefit from using g:G/G'→G? 
I am having troubles with it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you know how to check that $G'$ is normal subgroup, and thus that quotient $G/G'$ is well defined. I will also assume that you know how to check that canonical map $f= (x\mapsto xG')\colon G\to G/G'$ is indeed homomorphism, and not only that, it is epimorphism. I will also assume that you know [Fundamental theorem on homomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_on_homomorphisms) (and if you don't, this is what you definitely need to learn by heart before proceeding).

So, we need a map $\hom(G,A)\to \hom(G/G',A)$. Well, let's take a homomorphism $g\colon G\to A$. Now,

$g([x,y]) = g(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy) = g(x)^{-1}g(y)^{-1}g(x)g(y) = e_A$

because $A$ is Abelian. Since $G'$ is generated by commutators, we just proved that $G'\subseteq \ker g$. By fundamental theorem on homomorphisms we can induce unique map $\bar g\colon G/G'\to A$ defined by $\bar g(xG') = g(x)$. This gives us mapping $g\mapsto\bar g\colon \hom(G,A)\to \hom(G/G',A)$ which we will prove is desired isomorphism. Injectivity is easy:

$\bar g = \bar h \implies \bar g(xG') = \bar h(xG') \implies g(x) = h(x),\ \forall x\in G$

Surjectivity is hard...

Just kidding, it's just as easy. Well, let's say that we have $h\colon G/G'\to A$. I claim that $\overline{hf} = h$. Let's check it:

$\overline{hf}(xG') = (hf)(x) = h(f(x)) = h(xG'),\ \forall x\in G$.

That's all... almost. You might have noticed that I not only claimed to construct bijection, but *isomorphism*. Well, I will leave to you to check that $\hom(G,A)$ is Abelian group for any group $G$ and any Abelian group $A$ where multiplication is given component-wise, and that just constructed bijection is indeed group homomorhpism.

Comment: Great explanations, thank you very much. 
But having no function to define the bijection, I get the assumptions, but I don't know how to show injectiviy and surjectivity where I am not sure what I am to compare exactly... I'll be honest, weren't taught the homomorphism fundamental theorem so it made it a bit harder...

Comment: You are welcome. Well, you probably did learn first isomorphism theorem, right? This is the same idea. It can be shortly explained, actually. You can try to define $\bar g$ the same way I did, but you can't really be sure that it is well defined, meaning you don't know if $xH = yH$ implies $\bar g(xH) = \bar g(yH)$ for some normal subgroup $H\leq G$, unless $H\subseteq\ker g$.

Comment: Thank you... Sorry for delaying bounty... I would have to wait a specific amount of hours and today I've been swamped...

Comment: I'm glad to help, this is very nice question, and when you learn some category theory, you will find that this is actually the best possible way to turn general group into Abelian, and the key is precisely this isomorphism of hom sets. So, remember this example :)